# Is there a way to exclude indexing and ingest string columns in Druid?

Tags: druid

I have close to 5000 columns in a dataset and I am trying to create a Druid table out of it.
Question 1: Is there any suggestion/ better practice on how to ingest data of this magnitude?

What I have done so far ?
Question 2: I am trying to exclude few string columns from indexing for better performance. Is there a way to exclude string columns from indexing? My understanding is string columns will be part of the Dimension and it will index every string columns. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can turn off the indexing for string dimensions by setting bitmapindexing :false for the string dimensions. but this could still eat a lot of compute to store 5000 columns which is insane.